# change string to double quotes

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a collection of strings. I am trying to convert it to an array. The

```
   var company = "Toyota,Honda,Ford";
   var array = '[' + company.split( "," ).join( '"','"' ) + ']';  \\prints out "["Toyota"Honda"Ford"]" . It should be ["Toyota","Honda","Ford"]
   console.log(array);
```

array[0] should be Toyota and so on. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `company.split( "," )`. You are joining them using `.join(...)` which converts it back to a string.

[`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) already creates an array.

```js
var company = "Toyota,Honda,Ford";
var array = company.split( "," );
   console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish it a little more simplified by `split`ting, then `map`ing your quotes in there. I think your main problem is you're trying to do array operations and string operations. You shouldn't need to do any string operations other than your request to wrap your items in double-quotes. Other than that, you already split your string into an array since you have a `,` as a delimiter. So, simply make it an array, then wrap your elements with double-quotes.

Example:

```js
var company = "Toyota,Honda,Ford";
var array = company.split(',').map(c => `"${c}"`);
console.log(array[0]);
```